# how child thread status is collected in parent thread when child reaches exit before the parent reaches join?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

In my scenario, there is main thread which is creating 3 child threads using `pthread_create()`.

After creating child threads, child threads tasks are completed and reached `pthread_exit()` statement but parent still not reached the statement `pthread_join()` to collect the status of childs.

But somehow at the end, I am able to get the status of the threads in the parent thread.

How it is possible, please can help me in this?

Comment: In the end you mean afet joining? And since you're using threads, you always can read their variables so, you can see their status. But if you didn't take care of the syncronism in that common variables you can have usual paralelism problems.

Comment: So what's the actual problem?  The main thread will Join with some threads that are completed (and passively waiting).

Comment: @Henk Holterman, So, does it mean pthread_exit() will be in waiting state until the parent collects status?

Answer (score 1):

> So, does it mean pthread_exit() will be in waiting state until the
>   parent collects status?

`pthread_exit()` ends; the thread isn't *in waiting state*, but rather *a "zombie thread"*, as in this [note](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html#NOTES):

```
       Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not
       detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since each
       zombie thread consumes some system resources, and when enough zombie
       threads have accumulated, it will no longer be possible to create new
       threads (or processes).
```

(The `retval` is stored inside the `pthread_t` buffer.)